# How to check message received from registered device only in IBM Watson IOT- Node Red

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, node-red, watson-iot, device-management

Is there a way to identify the messages received is from the registered gateway or device in the organization.

I'm using IBM Watson IOT and Node-Red - editor to simulate send from device /gateway. here the question is after receiving message How can I check the received message is from the registered device/gateway?.

P:S if we subscribe to receive a message on the topic with all device type /device id /event id we may receive a message from unregistered device/gateway.

Appreciate help.Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand this.  Can anything send if it's not registered?  I would expect the Platform to have blocked it with a 404 or invalid token.  And if it can't send, it shouldn't be appearing in a subscription anywhere.

Comment: @amadain A gateway can forward data from a device that isn't already defined in IoT Platform, that creates the device browser entry for it. The device type must already exist, and of course the gateway must be authenticated (i.e. connected) before it can do this.

Comment: Thanks @barny, I had no idea that was possible. I guess i can understand why though, now I think on it.

Answer (score 2):

Watson IoT Platform security segregates data into organizations that can only be accessed by devices or applications registered to that specific organization.  See documentation [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/security/index.html#secure-org).

If you subscribe to receive a message on the topic with device type set to all, that would only be the devices, gateways and applications that are registered to that organization.  Unregistered devices and applications would be unable to put to that topic space.

[image]